# Can we enable Spring boot compression for specific URIs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, gzip

In our java springboot application, we have a requirement of compressing the REST response since the JSON structure is huge. While browsing through the web it was found that we can use the following properties in the application.properties to enable compression .

```
# Enable response compression
server.compression.enabled=true
 
# Minimum response where compression will kick in
server.compression.min-response-size=4096
 
# Mime types that should be compressed
server.compression.mime-types=text/html, text/xml, text/plain, text/css, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/json
```

It worked just fine, but it compressed all the responses returning from that server.

Is there any way to filter out this compression. For instance we want to compress only the responses with the URIs ending with *compress* or *merge*

Or if there is any other suggestion to achieve the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom user agent to the request you want to be filtered and configure in excluded user-agents in properties. Next put that user agent in requests.